# How to handle 301 redirect in aws go sdk

Tags: aws-sdk-go

I tried this example:

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/tree/main/example/service/s3/listObjects

and received a 301 redirection response, which is not handled in this example.

I also tried aws python SDK which seems handle 301 automatically. How can we config go aws client to handle 301 automatically like in python?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the Go library doesn't handle the 301 redirect automatically, which might be a good thing. Fetching large amounts of data between different regions may be expensive due to high egress.

If you do want to fetch data from another bucket, you should know where the bucket is located. Then create an S3 client that points to the correct region and use it. The S3 bucket region can be determined using [`manager.GetBucketRegion`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/feature/s3/manager#GetBucketRegion):

```golang
import "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/feature/s3/manager"
import "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3"

cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(ctx)
if err != nil {
  return err
}

s3client := s3.NewFromConfig(cfg)

bucket := "my-bucket"
region, err := manager.GetBucketRegion(ctx, s3client, bucket)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

if cfg.Region != region {
  regionCfg = cfg.Copy()
  regionCfg.Region = region
  s3client = s3.NewFromConfig(regionCfg)
}
```